# Firebase User verify Email Action URL to Custom URL

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I am developing an application using Angular and AngularFire. When A user is registering using email and password and the user is getting an verification email in his email. When I am changing that Action URL in Email address verification template to "http://localhost:4200/verify-email-address" then the user's email verified is still false, if I use the default URL then it is returning true. How can I set a custom Local template to show a user that his/her email is verified and redirect that user to login again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Customizing the email action handling requires more than just changing the URL. You're essentially taking over everything that Firebase normally does, and will need to call the relevant Firebase API (e.g. `auth.applyActionCode(actionCode)` to verify the email address) in various places during this processing.

The full process is described in the Firebase documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler). You'll typically want to copy the HTML + script from that page, get it working, and only make any customizations after that.

Comment: This needs a clarification. It *does* mean just changing the URL, if the URL you change it to is one used in Firebase Hosting (or dynamic links I think).

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who might want to do the above, we have just added a custom domain on Firebase Hosting, which means we can use that for the `<our-domain)/__/auth/action` and then just change the templates to use the custom domain.

Odd that this is not documented, but adding the custom domain to Firebase Hosting replaces everything in the project (e.g. this method is mentioned on Dynamic Links docs)

Comment: for a documented guide on the answer above, I have written an article a takes you through a step-by-step guide https://ifedapo.com/posts/customise-firebase-action-url.

You can also have a look at this StackOverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72591507/4088675