# Invalid Firebase Email/Password Auth Handler (missing providerId)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-identity

After using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` from `firebase/auth`, Firebase sends a verification email to the user.  The verification link successfully verifies the email, but instead of redirecting back to my app, I am redirected to the following URLs:

#### Local with the emulator:

```
http://localhost:9099/emulator/auth/handler?apiKey=fake-api-key&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D&authType=reauthViaRedirect&redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapp&v=9.21.0&eventId=VBnwo5RI30cI7UvoCwfBQfZXNmmm%3A%3A%3A7630387099
```

with the following error:

```
{ "authEmulator": { "error": "missing apiKey or providerId query parameters" } }
```

For local emulation on the backend, I am calling `admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink(email, { url: "http://localhost:3000/app"})` to generate an email verification link.  This link looks like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9099/emulator/action?mode=verifyEmail&lang=en&oobCode=XXX&apiKey=fake-api-key&continueUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapp
```

It leads to a verification success, then redirects automatically to `localhost:3000/app`, however it doesn't stay there long as that is when I am redirected to the error-state URL shown above.

#### And production:

```
https://example.com/__/auth/handler?apiKey=XXX&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D&authType=reauthViaRedirect&redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fapp%2Fregister%2Fverify-email&v=9.21.0&eventId=TIaOYg0R5QdkPxrXuZl5IClNFd52%3A%3A%3A9624473175
```

with the following error:

```
The requested action is invalid.
...
Request is missing required data
```

For production, I am letting Firebase handle the verification email by calling `sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser, { url: window.location.href })` on the front end.  I do NOT use a custom email action handler [[1]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503951/firebase-user-verify-email-action-url-to-custom-url). Instead, in the Firebase console, I set the action URL to `https://example.com/__/auth/action` with the proper domain verification [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972194/how-to-customize-firebase-action-url-for-password-reset-and-email-verification/72591507#72591507), but I've also tried it by resetting it to the default, and it causes the same behavior.  This is the link it generates:

```
https://example.com/__/auth/action?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=XXX&apiKey=XXX&continueUrl=https%3A%2F%example.com%2Fapp%2Fregister%2Fverify-email&lang=en
```

#### Additional Details

Note that if I simply navigate a second time to (local) `localhost:3000/app` or (prod) `https://example.com/app`, it doesn't redirect me incorrectly and everything works fine.

Curiously, if I add in `&providerId=password` to the query parameters, it works just fine; however, I have no idea what is generating this URL nor why it is not including the providerId (if that is even the root of the problem).  Any help in understanding what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you also share how you defined the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method and how you are Authenticating the User ? Have you used `actionCodeSettings` ? and also try initializing the Auth emulator with `connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://127.0.0.1:9099");`. If not worked then please provide more details.

Comment: @RohitKharche woops, sorry I misspoke.  It's with the call to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` that I get the error, not `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, which is how I'm authenticating the user.  I'm not using `actionCodeSettings`, just the default when using `admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink`; however, I'm only calling `generateEmailVerificationLink` locally.  In prod, I am letting Firebase handle the email verification step fully.  Switching from `http://localhost:9099` to `http://127.0.0.1:9099` in `connectAuthEmulator` still produced the error.

Comment: @RohitKharche I also added significantly more data to the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was resolved here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7303

TL:DR; The issue was calling `reauthenticateWithRedirect` while attempting to pass the `password` providerId to the call without providing a credential.

As soon as the email is verified, the firebase user itself is not authenticated (just the email verified).  I thought using `reauthenticateWithRedirect` would resolve this (and it does, but I need to give it the credential). It looks like for email/password the expectation is supposed to be that the user is forced to sign back in rather than being automatically reauthenticated?

There doesn't appear to be any way to reauthenticate the password method without having them reenter their credentials. The best bet is to call [reauthenticateWithCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#reauthenticatewithcredential) after extracting the email from the firebase user and asking the user to re-enter the password.

Here's an example:

```
const email = auth.currentUser.email;
const password = ???; // get from user-provided input
const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
await reauthenticateWithCredential(auth.currentUser, credential);
```

[Source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/8e9aac2eff5f6d5623c1412151b1c563b37ed8b7/packages/auth/demo/src/index.js#L445-L456)

Answer (score 1):

I have recreated the setup from what you have shared and
According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61389389/firebase-send-email-verification-to-user) and the answer provided by [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61389546/20239914)

> Verification emails can only be sent from the client-side SDK, and only after the user has signed in. This is done to prevent the ability to abuse Firebase's servers for sending spam.

So if you are using `admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink(email)` to send the email verification link to the user then it should be done through SMTP server the templates for that email is registered in your Firebase Console’s Authentication Templates Tab.

I will recommend you to send the email verification link from the Client SDK when the user is created using [**Send a user a verification email**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email) and to make your user return to your app. And make sure to add [ActionCodeSettings](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions#passing_statecontinue_url_in_email_actions) url which helps your users to return to your App.

Now Regarding the Error you got :
`http://localhost:9099/emulator/auth/handler` is what the client SDK will redirect to, but requires the client SDK in order to work
If you want to redirect the user to your app then you will need to add the redirect url inside the [ActionCodeSettings](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions#passing_statecontinue_url_in_email_actions).

**Update** :
If your app's homepage is `http://localhost:3000/app` then it should redirect you to there. But the `url` field of actionCodeSettings could have different meanings in the different context as per the docs :

```
(property) ActionCodeSettings.url: string

Sets the link continue/state URL.

@remarks
This has different meanings in different contexts:

1. When the link is handled in the web action widgets, this is the deep link in the continueUrl query parameter.
2. When the link is handled in the app directly, this is the continueUrl query parameter in the deep link of the Dynamic Link.
```

Your issue falls under 1st category so double check the url.

Comment: thanks for keeping the investigation going!  Unfortunately, the problem still persists.  I added the ActionCodeSetting with the url to `admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink(email, { url: "http://localhost:3000/app"})`, but that simply redirects to `http://localhost:3000/app` then immediately shows the error screen previously mentioned.  For production, I don't use `generateEmailVerificationLink` and instead use `sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser, { url: window.location.href })` from the frontend, and rely on the default Firebase email action handler with the same error

Comment: I've updated the OP with all these new details

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your latest **Update**.  I am setting the ActionCodeSettings.url to `http://localhost:3000/app`, which is what `continueUrl` is set to as part of `http://127.0.0.1:9099/emulator/action?...&continueUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapp`.  Are you saying that is wrong?  If so, what about it is wrong and what should it be instead?