# Firebase auth - how to change custom domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a question. Some time ago I've created a project in Firebase. I use only authorization component. I've added my custom domain. Everything ok.

But now, I had to change domain to another. **How can I change custom domain for email in auth?** At now links in emails are wrong.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the custom domain for email actions? eg. password reset, email verification, etc?

Comment: @bojeil yes. Password reset, email verification etc.

Comment: have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72591507/4088675

Answer (score 2):

You have to change it in the Firebase Console.

1. Select "Authentication" in the left menu.
2. Select "Templates" tab.
3. Click pencil button in any one of the email templates to edit it.
4. Click "customize action URL" link.
5. You can change the domain of the link there.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [using a custom domain for Authentication emails](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/email-custom-domain).

Comment: In the customize action url, I just want to show xxxapp.com instead of xxxapp.firebasepp.com in say the Password reset link, how would I set it up for that? Just changing the domain here doesn't work. I have hosting also set up for my domain so it is active.