# firebase / google authentication customize password reset link cannot use # in url

Tags: firebase-authentication

In firebase auth you can customize the email templates sent when a password reset is induced via an SDK call. In my flutter web app I have a password reset page from which a user can hit a button, it fires the appropriate call to a firebase function which requests one of those password reset emails.

That all works.

What doesn't work is when you try to customize the link sent in the email. I need a # in the link. If you try to put a # in the link it thinks it is a placeholder and puts the action codes (?oobCode=sjkf329203rj) where the # is. That wont do. I need the url to be formatted as I am trying to format it.

I need:
domain.com/#/passReset/?oobcode=23k2r3lkj23rj
not:
domain.com/?oobcode=23k2r3lkj23rj/#passReset

My app is a flutter webapp and it all works just fine, but one thing which is apparently necessary is the trailing # in the URL. The router in flutter happily picks up on urls and lets you respond to everything in the URL just fine as long as that # is in there. I.e. the router will allow me to see the presence of the 'passReset' and it will give me the variables as 'settings'. If the # isn't there however, it bugs out.

I don't want users sent to the ugly looking .firebase.app/...... url that google use with their 'built-in' password reset page supplied by firebase auth, that domain is not the domain of my site, and if they go to that other domain, reset their password on the form on the built in page then they are doing so on that different domain and chrome knows it. Then when they naturally tell chrome to remember the password - and then return back to my site to use that password chrome warns that my site is 'deceptive' because they are using the same password across two domains.

Note that the # being interpreted as a placholder is new. My whole flow was working a month ago. I still have the test emails to prove it. I am just about to launch a new site and someone spotted the links for password resets aren't working which is when I found all this.

I have logged a bug with google, but if anyone can think of a way round this? I have tried lots of chars to escape the # to force the authentication email generating software at google to leave my hash in there, but they just wont - the always put the codes in right there.

Comment: To set the domain that is linked from the email, see https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714?hl=en and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781532/firebase-auth-how-to-change-custom-domain