# How to implement 6-digit OTP via-email with Firebase Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

Project Platform: Unity (Android & iOS)

Backend: Google Firebase

As authentication via email link requires to setup Firebase Dynamic Link (as one of many steps of the steup process) which is also deprecated.

**Problem:** I'm trying to log in users with their email and every time I want to send them 6-digit OTP to their registered email, so they don't have to remember the password at all. For this, I need noreply@PROJECT_ID.firebase.com email and password (of maybe a service account) to send OTP, *without using any other third-party service for email*.

OR how I can add my own template in authentication for OTP and how to trigger that with specific details?

OR just thinking, does Firebase hosting also provides project emails?

I'm trying to make my own way of OTP using Firebase (using Firebase RealtimeDatabase), but just for my users to give the feel of OFFICIAL stuff, I want to use the project name as the email domain.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Are you asking [how to change the domain name in the emails that Firebase Authentication sends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781532/firebase-auth-how-to-change-custom-domain)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen no, as mainly I'm trying to login to my app users using OTP send through the email they register with using my Firebase Project email (maybe service account if they allow) without any third party. For that, I need a *noreply* email generated by my Firebase project which can send email