# Replace Firebase Project Name with Custom Domain in Email Templates with Action URL

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-authentication

**Background**

Firebase Authentication sends out emails for registration, password change etc. These emails contain links with the internal Firebase name of my project.

**Problem**

I want to replace that internal name with my custom domain, which seems to be possible by changing the Action URL and using a Dynamic Link.

I do not want to handle the email actions with my own code, but just replace the Firebase domain with a custom domain. It is about sending emails that are containing links with a custom domain and thus *look nice*.

**Existing Answer**

An answer exists, but I do not understand how this exactly works. And I am not able to comment as my reputation is too low.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972194/how-to-customize-firebase-action-url-for-password-reset-and-email-verification#:~:text=You%20just%20need%20to%20create,Dynamic%20Link%20and%20hit%20done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972194/how-to-customize-firebase-action-url-for-password-reset-and-email-verification#:%7E:text=You%20just%20need%20to%20create,Dynamic%20Link%20and%20hit%20done).

**Illustration**

[image: Customizing the action URL]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize firebase action URL for password reset and email verification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972194/how-to-customize-firebase-action-url-for-password-reset-and-email-verification)

Comment: I've found a way to customize the domain without the need to create a new webpage here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67579542/8332099

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72591507/4088675. I faced this issue recently, and after solving it, I posted the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible change the Firebase action URL in email templates to one's custom domain without implementing email action handler code but relying on the already existing firebase functionality.

In the Firebase Console:

1. Go to **Dynamic Links**
2. **Add URL Prefix** by entering your custom domain `YOURDOMAIN.com`. No need to actually add a Dynamic Link, this entry alone is sufficient.
3. Go to **Authentication** > **Template** > **Edit (Pencil)** > **Customize Action URL**
4. Enter your custom domain according to this pattern (note the *TWO* underscores):

`https://YOURDOMAIN.com/__/auth/action`

5. Send out an email by registering to your App and click the link in the email. The link will bring you to the default Firebase page handling the action.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is very well explained in this [documentaion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler). you have to:

1- create the email action handler page

2- link that page to your email template in the **customize action url**

Comment: As written above, I'd like to avoid setting up my own email handler. It is a question of cosmetics, not functionality.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to customize the domain without actually creating your own account managment server. it's also [described here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714?hl=en)

Comment: To my surprise it is possible, I figured it out. See my answer below.