# Change firebase email base url to custom domain

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am using firebase admin api to generate email links in cloud functions. I have my own locale specific templates and I embed url's generated by below api's in my template. Finally i use nodemailer to send the email.

```
admin.auth().generatePasswordResetLink(email)
admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink(email)
```

But for some reason the links generated by the API are not using custom domain. Any ideas ? Is admin api not respecting the console configuration ?

I have configured custom domain via firebase console.
[image]

Comment: This seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64729583

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72591507/4088675.