# Use multiple domains for Firebase password reset

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I haven't figured out a way to customize the authentication domain for a password reset email. This is important because I have built a custom password reset page, and need to first test it in localhost, and then in production once it is deployed. I am using a cloud function written in Python to send out the password reset email using the following code:

```
def send_password_reset_email(request):
    if request.method == "OPTIONS":
        return handle_preflight_request()
    
    data = request.json["data"]
    reset_mode = data["reset_mode"]
    user_email = data["user_email"]
    base_url = data["base_url"]

    settings = auth.ActionCodeSettings(url=base_url)
    reset_link = auth.generate_password_reset_link(
        email=user_email, action_code_settings=settings, app=firebase_app
    )
```

Even if I pass in different urls for `base_url`, the same reset link is generate. How do I create different reset links depending on if I'm in localhost/development or in production here?

Answer (score 1):

As per this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler), it is mentioned that

> “By default, user management emails link to the default action
> handler, which is a web page hosted at a URL in your project's
> Firebase Hosting domain”.

There are 4 different approaches to customize the authentication domain for a password reset email depending on your functionality and use case:

1. Change the Firebase action URL by customizing one's domain and the
   action link URL without implementing email action handler code as
   per this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64729583/15803365).

In the Firebase Console:

- Go to Dynamic Links
- Add URL Prefix by entering your custom domain YOURDOMAIN.com. No need
  to actually add a Dynamic Link, this entry alone is sufficient.
- Go to `Authentication > Template > Edit (Pencil) > Customize Action URL`
- Enter your custom domain according to this pattern -
  `https://YOURDOMAIN.com/__/auth/action`

2. You can [create a Firebase Dynamic link of your custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions#configuring_firebase_dynamic_links) .After
   creating Firebase Dynamic Link, go to Authentication/Templates on
   Firebase, and click on the Customize URL of your action link and enter the
   Dynamic Link . Your Default Action URL link will be altered.
3. You can [create and host a custom email action handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) to do custom
   processing and to integrate the email action handler with your
   website.Then, you must customize your Firebase project's email templates
   to [link to your custom action handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler#link_to_your_custom_handler_in_your_email_templates).
4. To [specify a sender address with a custom domain and use your own server
   to handle account management emails](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714?hl=en), specify the URL to your server's
   account management page by following the Firebase support article.