# how to change firebase email verify action url?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to change the email confirmation url. Currently the url is **https://localhost:3000/__/auth/action** , but when I redirect to this url, I see that the email is not approved.

Comment: There is almost the same problem, check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972194/how-to-customize-firebase-action-url-for-password-reset-and-email-verification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-To configure your Firebase project to use your custom email action handler you can follow below steps:

1. Open your project in the Firebase console
2. Go to the Email Templates page in the Auth section.
3. In any of the Email Types entries, click the pencil icon to edit the
   email template.
4. Click customize action URL, and specify the URL to your custom email
   action handler.

After you save the URL, it will be used by all of your Firebase project's email templates. You can refer detail information from below doc: 
[Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler)
[Email verification in firebase Auth](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/02/email-verification-in-firebase-auth.html)

-You can create Dynamic Links into an app that work whether or not users have installed the app yet.

1. Create a Firebase Dynamic link of your custom domain
2. After Creating Firebase Dynamic Link, go to Authentication/Templates
   on     Firebase, and click on Customize URL of your action link and
   type your     Dynamic Link.
3. Your Default Action URL should change.

For more details please refer document:
[Create Dynaminc link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains)